# Will Windows 7 support the Oracle 10G client?

Tags: windows-7, oracle10g

Has anyone heard whether Oracle will support the 10G client Windows 7? I am forced (very unwilling since I started out on SQL Server) to deal with Oracle dev every day and since 7 is "just a polished Vista" (I feel it is far superior and I've been using Vista since RTM) the theory is that it will work fine.

Also, if this is the wrong place to ask this please let me know. Since it's dev-releated, I didn't think it belonged on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working (10.2.0.4) on Windows 7! Following the recommendations from [this](http://msutic.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-instal-oracle-client-11g-on.html) blog post I changed the XML and installed the client (10.2.0.3 I believe). To install the patch set for 10.2.0.4 (gives you transactional support on Vista/2008) you run the installer in compatibility mode. While I haven't had a chance to try the transactional support I've at least confirmed the Benthic tool Golden works fine which is further than I've ever gotten before.

This was done on Windows 7 x64 - Oracle client is x86 version as they don't have an x64 of the patch set for transactional support (nor does it exist in some flavors of 11G, however that is possible).

I hope this helps others with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

The *right* place to ask it would probably be the Oracle support forums but I'm not going to vote to close since you were so nice about it in the last paragraph. See [here](http://forums.oracle.com/).

[This one](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3640806) is probably the most helpful. Basically, there'll be no support until at least Win7 goes GA. How long after that before Oracle pulls their stuff together and supports it is anybody's guess.

One possibility to consider: I heard talk Microsoft was going to put a virtual machine manager into Win7 to try and convince all the XP bods to upgrade. That appears to still be the case as documented [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/get-started.aspx) on Microsoft's own site. If so, you could run Oracle 10g under the VM.

Comment: So, ironically enough, I am digitall on the Oracle Forums. I asked here because the people over on that side of the fence are far less than helpful to say the least (and I haven't seen a response to that thread in a week).

Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post and ran across the same problem. I also saw your post over [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3640806) that said you were able to get it working using 'option 2' that Justin Cave suggested. Were you able to get that working? Could you describe the process in some more detail?

UPDATE: As a follow-up, we were actually able to get it working. Here's how: create a shortcut with the -ignoreSysPrereqs flag on the executable. Run the executable as Administrator, and do NOT use Vista or any compatibility modes. We also installed a loopback adapter ([as described here](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/how-to-install-a-loopback-adapter-in-windows-7/)), although I do not know if that had any impact. It works as needed on the developers machines and we appreciate the research you put into this! :)

Comment: When you go to run their installer (the one that makes you reminisce a bit about Windows 95 UX and how nice it was...) you have to do so from a command prompt and add in the "-ignoreSysPrereqs" switch after the exe name. It only sort of works though and I haven't had much luck with the RTM either.

Comment: As a follow-up, we were actually able to get it working. Here's how: create a shortcut with the -ignoreSysPrereqs flag on the executable. Run the executable as Administrator, and do NOT use Vista or any compatibility modes. We also installed a loopback adapter as described here (http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/how-to-install-a-loopback-adapter-in-windows-7/), although I do not know if that had any impact. It works as needed on the developers machines and we appreciate the research you put into this! :)

Comment: Also of note, you have to manually check and ignore the other items listed in the install process. No worries - it works.

Comment: As a follow-up, this will only sort of work. If you happen to need the 10.2.0.4 patch set (allows distributed transactions to work) then Oracle won't be supporting it on 7 or 2008 R2. They will only support it with the 11G client (certification pending) and higher. Of course, the 11G client doesn't necessarily have the same patches that 10G does so we might all be switching to SQL server in the future to get a real database platform (personally I hate Oracle a LOT).

Comment: It worked for development purposes, and that's all we needed it for. Thanks anyway for the follow-up :)

Comment: 11g being the current version has all the fixes that have been added to 10g as well. 11g installs under 7/2008 without any issues.